# QLineEdit Clear Text on Click and Read Text from Button

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am looking to clear the text that I have written on my QLineEdit for a GUI form when the user clicks on the field. I also want one of the fields to be an **** because it will represent a password field.

Lastly, when the user clicks a button, how can I get the text in the field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a part of the question about password please look at `QLineEdit::EchoMode` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#EchoMode-enum). There are `QLineEdit::Password` and `QLineEdit::PasswordEchoOnEdit`, they might be interesting for you.